# How to fix AttributeError Using Python/Pygame classes and Printing Attribute Contents to Terminal

Tags: python

Please instruct me on how would I resolve this issue and how to check if the class attributes are indeed sorting the intended values. The program below in meant to display a colored monitor within a monitor when the program is run.

However, I am having a consistent issue with a traceback of "AttributeError: type object 'monitor' has no attribute 'x' ". I am not sure if the classmethod portion in the original class is part of the issue.

The code is as listed below.

```
import pygame
import os
import math 

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class monitor(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, length, width, offset, offsetcolor):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.color = color
            self.color =(100,100,100)
            self.length = length
            self.width = width
            self.offset = offset
            self.offsetcolor = offsetcolor
                
    @classmethod  
    def draw(cls, win):
        #attribute checker
        if hasattr(cls, m.x):
                print("Monitor's X attribute is ", {cls.x})
            
            else:
                print("Monitor's x feature is not working...")
        
                #monitor drawing
        border = pygame.Rect(cls.x, cls.y, cls.width, cls.length)
            oborder = pygame.Rect(cls.x + cls.offset, cls.y + cls.offset, cls.width - (10* cls.offset), cls.length - (10* cls.offset))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, cls.color, border)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, cls.offsetcolor, oborder)
        print(cls.color + ' ' +cls.offsetcolor)
        my_monitor = monitor(10, 10, (255, 0, 0), 100, 50, 5, (0, 255, 0))
        my_monitor.draw(win)
        pygame.display.update()

        def redrawGameWindow():
                monitor.draw(win)

#mainloop & variables 
m = monitor(100,100,(100,100,100), 800, 1000, 2, (150,150,150))
m.x = 100
m.y = 100
m.width = 1000
m.length = 800
m.offset = 2

while run:
    clock.tick(27)
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
    run = False
    pygame.quit()
        
    #if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    redrawGameWindow()           
  
pygame.quit()
```

For reference, all other features of this code was working prior to me using the Class Oriented model.

Full Traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Monitor.py", line 115, in <module>
    redrawGameWindow()           
  File "Monitor.py", line 70, in redrawGameWindow
    monitor.draw(win)
  File "Monitor.py", line 45, in draw
    border = pygame.Rect(cls.x, cls.y, cls.width, cls.length)
AttributeError: type object 'monitor' has no attribute 'x'
```

I have swapped the attributes around to see if I could go around this error but nothing but only cls seems to work for the classmethod portion when I attempt to draw the monitor. Do classmethods require a different means to inherit attributes than normal methods?

I have also attempted to place the same variables in the main loop as a way of passing those values to the monitor.draw() function, but I still end up with the same issue. Are those variables within the mainloop redundant aside from using them to enact in game rules or are they necessary for initial placement of the monitor?

I have also attempted to have the attribute print to terminal to see if there is indeed a value logged there, but I am having no luck with it. Could someone clarify what is missing and how to catch these errors going forward?

Comment: Please show the full traceback so we can see where the error is happening.

Comment: The `draw()` method will only work if you assign the monitor to a variable named `m`. This is a very poor design, it means you can't have multiple instances of the class.

Comment: `m.x` is a number. It makes no sense to use that as the second argument to `hasattr()`.

Comment: Why do you assign `m.x` , `m.y`, etc. immediately after creating it? Those attributes are set in the `__init__()` method, you don't need to repeat them.

Comment: `{cls.x}` is the problem. `x` is an attribute of instances, not the class itself.

Comment: `draw()` should be an ordinary method, not `@classmethod`. Then you can use `hasattr(self, "x")` and `{self.x}`.

Comment: @Barmar Full Traceback is now listed. Also, when I attempted to run the program as a normal method, I get this traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Monitor.py", line 116, in <module>
    redrawGameWindow()           
  File "Monitor.py", line 76, in redrawGameWindow
    monitor.draw(win)
TypeError: unbound method draw() must be called with monitor instance as first argument (got Surface instance instead)

Comment: @Barmar Being that the current draw() method is not a good design, what would be a better way of allowing for multiple instances of the class?

Comment: Like I said, it should be an instance method, then you can use `self.x`, `self.y`, etc.

Comment: I recommend you discard your `classmethod` approach and implement your monitor as a pygame [sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

Comment: @Barmar I have implemented those changes but I still get a different error mentioning about; Traceback (most recent call last): File "Monitor.py", line 116, in <module> redrawGameWindow() File "Monitor.py", line 76, in redrawGameWindow monitor.draw(win) TypeError: unbound method draw() must be called with monitor instance as first argument (got Surface instance instead).                                                          How do I make this argument make into a bound method and avoid this traceback unbound method traceback error?

Comment: @importrandom Thank you for your suggestion. While I could use a sprite, in this case I wish to specifically draw onto the screen using the built in functionality of pygame. I already know how to use sprites; I am trying to clarify for this specific feature. If this functionality is any more irritating, I might just go that route anyway for simplicity, but I am trying to avoid giving up, if you catch my drift.

Answer (score -1):

I've modified your code to eliminate the errors and tidied it a little, although that involves ignoring/subverting the *classmethod* intent.

```
import pygame
import os
import math 

class monitor(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, length, width, offset, offsetcolor):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.color = color
            self.color =(100,100,100)
            self.length = length
            self.width = width
            self.offset = offset
            self.offsetcolor = offsetcolor
                
    @classmethod  
    def draw(cls, instance, win):
        border = pygame.Rect(instance.x, instance.y, instance.width, instance.length)
        oborder = pygame.Rect(instance.x + instance.offset, instance.y + instance.offset, instance.width - (10* instance.offset), instance.length - (10* instance.offset))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, instance.color, border)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, instance.offsetcolor, oborder)

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
my_monitor = monitor(10, 10, (255, 0, 0), 100, 50, 5, (0, 255, 0))  
m = monitor(100,100,(100,100,100), 800, 1000, 2, (150,150,150))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False

    monitor.draw(m, win)
    monitor.draw(my_monitor, win)
    pygame.display.update()       
    clock.tick(27)
    
pygame.quit()
```

To implement with a sprite is more idiomatic:

```
class Monitor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, length, width, offset, offsetcolor):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width + 2*offset, length + 2*offset), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        border = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, length)
        oborder = pygame.Rect(offset, offset, width - (10* offset), length - (10* offset))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, border )
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, offsetcolor, oborder )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    
    def update(self):
        pass
```

You can use sprite groups to manage them as well:

```
monitors = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_monitor = Monitor(10, 10, (255, 0, 0), 100, 50, 5, (0, 255, 0))  
m = Monitor(100,100,(100,100,100), 800, 1000, 2, (150,150,150))
monitors.add(m, my_monitor)
```

This then makes your gameloop simple:

```
 # update state
monitors.update()
# draw background
win.fill("black")
# draw sprites
monitors.draw(win)
# update screen
pygame.display.update()       
clock.tick(27)
```

Note that your borders probably don't look like you intend them to, but once you see them it will be easier to figure out how to fix them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I'm going to try it on my end. I would upvote your contribution if this dumb reputation system wasn't preventing me from doing so. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Good luck @TechDude. You can always edit your question if there's progress but not a solution. If the progress transforms into a different problem, then you should ask a new question. The reputation limits are presumably to stop folks from creating sock-puppet accounts to upvote their poorly regarded answers. If you arrive at a different solution, you can [submit and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).